# Segmentation fault in program which creates a vector from a string

Tags: c++, arrays, fault

I got a Segmentation fault in the following program.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> split_words(std::string s) {
    std::vector<std::string> v(1, "");
    int i=0;
    int wortanzahl = 0;
    while(i<s.size()) {
        if (s[i]!=' ') {
            v.resize(wortanzahl + 1, "");
            for (int j=i; s[j]!=' '; ++j) {
                v[wortanzahl] += s[j];
                i=j;
            }
            ++wortanzahl;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "Alpha beta! Gamma";
    split_words(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::istringstream` to split the words on a space.  You don't need to write these types of loops to do this job.

Comment: Make sure you have a debug build, and run the program under your debugger. When the segmentation fault occurs, it will show you the line where it happened, and the program state. Or, you can examine an existing core file. PS, nothing stops `j` running off the end ...

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know the reason

You have several issues with your code.  The one glaring one is that you failed to return the vector `v` in the `split_words` function.  Not returning a value from a function that is defined to return a value is *undefined behavior*.

The second issue is that `j` falls off the end on the last word, since your loop only stops on `s[j]` being a blank.  The string does not end on a blank character, thus your loop keeps going beyond the length of the string.

Having said this, if your goal is to split a string on the space character, there is no need to write code like this to do the job.  Instead, simply use `std::istringstream` and `operator >>`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> split_words(std::string s) 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string temp;
    while (iss >> temp)
       v.push_back(temp);
    return v;
}
 
int main() 
{
   std::string s = "Alpha beta! Gamma";
   auto vect = split_words(s);
   for (auto& word : vect)
      std::cout << word << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/OeFJMJ)

The loop simply calls `operator >>` on the stream, and each iteration calls `push_back` for each parsed string encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I think, provided that you're using C++11 or higher, that you should go for regular expressions, and do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> split_words(std::string s) {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::regex pattern("[!-~]+");
    std::cmatch result;

    while(regex_search(s.c_str(), result, pattern)) {
        for(auto it : result)
           v.push_back(it);
        s = result.suffix().str();
    }

    return v;
}
```

So that your search matches every single (non-extended) ASCII table character combination except non printable ones, including spaces, and you achieve your aim.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is right here when you get to the last word you forget to check for `\0` or the length of the string.

```
for (int j=i; s[j]!=' ' && j < s.size(); ++j) {
  v[wortanzahl] += s[j];
  i=j;
}
```

Ah forgot I had seen Alexsandrescu talk about sentinels, so you could actually have solved the problem if you had added a  (space) after the input.
As first line in your `split_words` add

```
s += ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

These changes are required. Also mentioned inline in code below.

// 0. can try `using namespace std;` to clean up code.

// 1. check for end of string in below loop.

// 2. return the vector of strings. (this fixes the crash).

// 3. output the split strings using vector.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// 0. can try using std to clean up code.
std::vector<std::string> split_words(std::string s)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v(1, "");
    int i=0;
    int wortanzahl = 0;
    while(i<s.size())
    {
        if (s[i]!=' ')
        {
            v.resize(wortanzahl+1, "");
            // 1. check for end of string in below loop
            for (int j=i; s[j] && s[j]!=' '; ++j)
            {
                v[wortanzahl] += s[j];
                i=j;
            }
            ++wortanzahl;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    // 2. return the vector of strings
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Alpha beta! Gamma";
    std::vector<std::string> v = split_words(s);

    // 3. output the split strings using vector
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```