# Split String to Vector with Whitespaces c++ error

Tags: c++, string, vector, split

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


vector<string> split_string(string s)
{
string buf;
stringstream ss(s);

vector<string> tokens;

while (ss >> buf)
    tokens.push_back(buf);

return tokens;
}


int main()
{
   cout << split_string("Alpha Beta Gamma");
}
```

when i try to split a string into a vector by using whitespaces i am not able to print out my solution.

i doesnt let me use std::cout but in my function the return value is given

why cant i use it like that? how do i fix this?

Comment: There is no overload operator<< for std::vector.

Comment: Is this is the same assignment as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872311/segmentation-fault-in-program-which-creates-a-vector-from-a-string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout` cannot take a vector, you need to iterate through the container and print each element separately, try using something like this:

```
int main()
{
    string originalString = "Alpha Beta Gamma";  

    for (const auto& str : split_string(originalString))
        cout << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```